# Why is const int fine for char brace init?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, narrowing

I thought brace initialization doesn't allow narrowing. But why is `int const` allowed for `char` brace initialization?

```
int value1 = 12;
char c1{value1};  // error! no narrowing

const int value2 = 12;
char c2{value2};   // why is this fine?
```

See it [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/mCzhfj).

Comment: Which compiler and which options are you using? It depends on this as well!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ```
> const int value2 = 12;
> ```

`value2` is a compile-time constant. The compiler can easily (and has to) prove that the value is 12 which happens to be within the range of values representable by `char`.

> ```
> int value1 = 12;
> ```

`value1` is not a compile-time constant. The value of the variable could change at runtime.

The exact wording of the standard rule (quoting latest draft, emphasis added):

> [[dcl.init.list]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7)
>
> A *narrowing conversion* is an implicit conversion
>
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, **except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type**.